# Compare column value by group in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, compare

My crystal skills are average. So I need help!!! Report has just one group on emp_id and has few other columns but the column I am interested in, is the coverage_id for each employee, if that has changed for any emp_id , I want emp_id and that emp_id's details to show all other emp_id should be supressed.

I have tried, whilerecordprinting, creating formula, previous, next nothing is working.....

Here is an e.g. of what the report is showing currently, I need only Emp_id 124 to be displayed on the report. Hope this helps...cannot add image yet.. Thanks..

Emp_Id, Service_DT,Coverage_ID

123  , 1/1/12    ,   2255

123 , 2/3/12    ,    2255

124 ,  3/11/12  ,    5566

124 ,  12/1/11   ,   2255

Comment: you need to explain your dataset. just give us a few rows and explain how you want the logic to work to show desired rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a distinct count of Coverage_ID to determine if it has changed for a given Emp_Id and use that as a suppression formula for your report sections.

Go into the Section Expert and add this formula as a suppression formula for each section you do not want to display (likely GroupHeader#1, Details, and GroupHeader#2) `distinctcount({Coverage_ID},{Emp_Id}) < 2`

Note that the second parameter to distinctcount() specifies that it is counting per employee grouping. That will cause no employee data to show in the report if they only have one Coverage_ID, otherwise it will be displayed.

Comment: That was so simple yet genius, I feel silly I did not come up with that.  Thank you !!!!!